# Export CSV for Excel

Tags: php, excel

I'm writing a CSV file in PHP using `fputcsv($file, $data)`. 
It all works, however I can't just open it in Excel but have to import it and specify the encoding and which delimiter to use (in a wizard). 
I've seen exports from other websites that open correctly just by clicking on them and now would like to know what I should do to my file to achieve that.

I tried using this library: http://code.google.com/p/parsecsv-for-php/
But I couldn't even get it to run and am not really confident if it would really help me...

Comment: Look in your windows region configuration settings. Make sure the delimiter is  a comma.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Despite the "C=comma" in CVS, Excel uses your locale native separator. So supposing `fputcsv` always uses a comma, it won't work, if your locale separator is for example a semicolon.

What Google AdSense does, when you click *"Export to Excel CSV"*, is that it uses <kbd>Tab</kbd> as a separator. And that works.

To replicate that, set the third parameter (`delimiter`) of `fputcsv` to override the default comma. E.g. for <kbd>Tab</kbd> use: `fputcsv($handle, $fields, "\t");`

*Compare the format of the CSV that works for you against the one generated by `fputcsv`.*

*Consider including example of both in your question. You might get better answers.*

Comment: Changing to my locale delimiter did it, thanks! I'll leave the accept-language out for the moment ;-)

Comment: Try also the Google `Tab` solution. It might be locale-independent.

Comment: Tried the "\t" solution but it didn't help (but haven't tried figuring with my locale settings honestly)

Answer (score 10):

This is how I make Excel readable CSV files from PHP  :

- Add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
- Set semi-colon (;) as delimeter
- Set correct header ("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8")

For exemple :

```
$headers = array('Lastname :', 'Firstname :');
$rows = array(
    array('Doe', 'John'),
    array('Schlüter', 'Rudy'),
    array('Alvarez', 'Niño')
);

// Create file and make it writable

$file = fopen('file.csv', 'w');

// Add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel

fputs($file, $bom = (chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)));

// Headers
// Set ";" as delimiter

fputcsv($file, $headers, ";");

// Rows
// Set ";" as delimiter

foreach ($rows as $row) {

    fputcsv($file, $row, ";");
}

// Close file

fclose($file);

// Send file to browser for download

$dest_file = 'file.csv';
$file_size = filesize($dest_file);

header("Content-Type: text/csv; charset=utf-8");
header("Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"file.csv\"");
header("Content-Length: " . $file_size);
readfile($dest_file);
```

Works with Excel 2013.

Comment: The delimiter must be a comma (,) and CSV stands for: Comma Separated Values. But this example was helpful where I only changed the delimiter from (;) to (,).

Comment: The answer is good. To nuance: Microsoft always has is own way of implementing things, CSV file reading/writing not being any different. They apparently chose the semicolon over the usual comma. Not too weird, because CSV can also take tab or pipe as separator, as long as you know it is safe for your data to do so _and_ you specify this in your import. The term CSV is now more designating the type of file (i.e. _Character_ separated values) rather than what it actually should be (Comma).

Answer (score 6):

this is really a mess. You surely can use the sep=; or sep=, or sep=\t or whatever to make Excel aware of a separator used in your CSV. Just put this string at the beginning of your CSV contents. E.g.:

```
fwrite($handle, "sep=,\n");

fputcsv($handle,$yourcsvcontent);
```

This works smoothly. BUT, it doesn't work in combination with a BOM which is required to make Excel aware of UTF-8 in case you need to support special characters or MB respectively.

In the end to make it bullet-proof you need to read out users locale and set the Separator accordingly, as mentioned above.
Put a BOM `("\xEF\xBB\xBF")` at the begining of your CSV content, then write the CSV like e.g.: `fputcsv($handle, $fields, $user_locale_seperator);`
where `$user_locale_seperator` is the separtator you retrieved by checking the user's locale.
Not comfortable but it works...

Comment: I was looking for this line for weeks. fputcsv does not work with the spearator, but fwrite does!

Answer (score 1):

You may have an encoding issue.

Try this post:

http://onwebdev.blogspot.com.es/2010/10/php-encoding-of-csv-file-for-excel.html

Comment: Did not solve it, but the encoding was another problem and your link help really well

Answer (score 1):

I notice that you need to consider:
`Content-Type` header
BOM (Byte Order Mark)
Actual character encoding in the file

With BOM (works):

```
$bom = pack("CCC", 0xEF, 0xBB, 0xBF);
header('Content-Type: text/csv');
header('Content-Length: '.(strlen($csv)+strlen($bom)));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=my.csv');
echo $bom;
echo $csv;
```

Without BOM (works but you need to replace “smart quotes” then run `utf8_decode` on each value or cell, and it converts some characters, for example FRĒ is converted to FRE')

```
header('Content-Type: application/csv;charset=utf-8');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($csv));
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename=my.csv');
echo $csv;
```

If the wrong combination of charset and BOM are used, it just comes out wrong when opening in MS Excel.

Bonus fact:  `mb_strlen` tells you the number of characters, `strlen` tells you the number of bytes.  You do **NOT** want to use `mb_strlen` for calculating the Content-Length header.

Bonus 2: replace microsoft "smart" characters (em dash, curly quotes, etc):

```
$map = array(chr(145) => "'"
            ,chr(146) => "'"
            ,chr(147) => '"'
            ,chr(148) => '"'
            ,chr(149) => '-'
            ,chr(150) => '-'
            ,chr(151) => '-'
            ,chr(152) => '-'
            ,chr(152) => '-'
            ,chr(171) => '-'
            ,chr(187) => '-'
);
// faster that strtr
return str_replace( array_keys($map), $map, $str );
```