# How to include UTF-8 BOM to a CSV export with Zend

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-framework2

I have the option to export some data in my project to a .csv file, i already have the charset set to UTF-8 in the response headers, however, Excel won't open as UTF-8 just by double clicking the file, and i would like to keep the process as user-friendly as possible, so i would like to avoid the need to manually import it.

From what i googled, i will need to include the UTF-8 BOM (0xEF,0xBB,0xBF) characters on the start of the file, but i don't really know how i can do that with PHP, here is my current code:

```php
$response = $this->getResponse();

$headers = $response->getHeaders();
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Type', 'text/csv charset=UTF-8');
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Disposition', "attachment; filename=\"{$_GET['file']}\"");
$headers->addHeaderLine('Accept-Ranges', 'bytes');
$headers->addHeaderLine('Content-Length', strlen($data_file));

$response->setContent($data_file);

return $response;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't have the reps yet to comment, but you're probably looking for this solution right here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49561209/3323348

On the other hand, if you target Excel users and you would like to make the whole import experience as seemless as possible than you might want to consider to create .xlsx files instead of CSVs (with the help of libraries like [PHPOffice spreadsheet](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) - make sure to read about how to populate a sheet [from an array](https://phpspreadsheet.readthedocs.io/en/latest/topics/accessing-cells/#setting-a-range-of-cells-from-an-array)).